# ODBC Connection Command Text

Tags: vba, excel

I use the below statement successfully many times in my VBA code.

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query").ODBCConnection
    .CommandText = SqlStat
    .Refresh
End With
```

I'm populating SQLStat based on parameters that are entered into Excel and inserted into the rest of the query.

One of these parameters is from a column range within Excel. I have the below code to loop through the range, and get every value within this to put into one string, separated by commas. 
I then use this string within an IN statement on my query so it only returns the results that I want.

```
' Gets List of Cust-SPA-Var
i = 3
' Gets column number
col_n = Sheets("Data").Range("N2").Value
'Determine the last row with data in column on Rebate List worksheet
lastRow = Sheets("Rebate Lists").Cells(Rows.Count, col_n).End(xlUp).Row

'Fills Down lookup Formula
Sheets("Rebate Lists").Select
    Sheets("Rebate Lists").Cells(3, col_n).Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("tblCustSPAVar[Cust-SPA-Var]"), Type:=xlFillDefault

' Loops through each row, checks if it exists in the string and if not, appends it to the end.
Do Until i = (lastRow + 1)
    If InStr(CustSPAVar, Sheets("Rebate Lists").Cells(i, col_n).Value) Then
        Else: CustSPAVar = CustSPAVar & "'" & Sheets("Rebate Lists").Cells(i, col_n).Value & "', "
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

The problem comes if there are lots of CustSPAVar values when running the code. When it gets to populating the command text, I get an Application-defined or object-defined error.

If I debug.print(SqlStat) then manually copy the SQL code out of the immediate window, the SQL code is correct. I can even update the query manually to use the copied SQL and it accepts and returns the results I'm expecting.

Doing a character count on the output of SqlStat it comes to over 50,000 characters.

What is the maximum characters I can populate CommandText with and is there any way around it?

Comment: [From this link](http://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/50819/too-long-sql-in-excel-vba.html) - The maximum permitted length for a querytable.commandtext is 32,767 chars. If you attempt to assign a larger string, you will trigger an object-defined error.

Comment: Is there any possible workaround to this limit?
Normally I'd use aliases for my tables, but the select part of the statement is tiny, it's the list of parameters that are the main bulk of text and obviously I can't cut them down.

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to go beyond the limit.  Can you break the query into several queries.  i.e. Store the first query into a temporary table and then query the temp table further?

Comment: The query is actually 2 unioned together. I suppose I could break them apart then combine the results set later on in code, but in the future the parameter list could be 2x as long as it currently is, and so that still won't get around the problem as I suspect each query would easily be over 32,000 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, there was no way to get around the limit.

I had to insert the parameters into a temporary CSV file on the fly, then reference this within the query using OPENROWSET

VBA:

```
' Saves Rebate Variants as CSV file in Temp directory.
Sheets("Rebate Variants").Select
Sheets("Rebate Variants").Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=TempPath & "\Variants.csv", _
    FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWindow.Close

If Len(Dir(TempPath & "\Variants.csv", vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Error creating " & TempPath & "\Variants.csv"
    Exit Sub
End If






' Creates the XML files definition
XmlText = _
"<?xml version=" & Chr(34) & "1.0" & Chr(34) & "?> " & Chr(13) & _
"<BCPFORMAT xmlns=" & Chr(34) & "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" & Chr(34) & " xmlns:xsi=" & Chr(34) & "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" & Chr(34) & "> " & Chr(13) & _
 "<RECORD> " & Chr(13) & _
  "<FIELD ID=" & Chr(34) & "1" & Chr(34) & " xsi:type=" & Chr(34) & "CharTerm" & Chr(34) & " TERMINATOR=" & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & " MAX_LENGTH=" & Chr(34) & "510" & Chr(34) & " COLLATION=" & Chr(34) & "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" & Chr(34) & "/> " & Chr(13) & _
  "<FIELD ID=" & Chr(34) & "2" & Chr(34) & " xsi:type=" & Chr(34) & "CharTerm" & Chr(34) & " TERMINATOR=" & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & " MAX_LENGTH=" & Chr(34) & "510" & Chr(34) & " COLLATION=" & Chr(34) & "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" & Chr(34) & "/> " & Chr(13) & _
    "<FIELD ID=" & Chr(34) & "3" & Chr(34) & " xsi:type=" & Chr(34) & "CharTerm" & Chr(34) & " TERMINATOR=" & Chr(34) & "\r\n" & Chr(34) & " MAX_LENGTH=" & Chr(34) & "510" & Chr(34) & " COLLATION=" & Chr(34) & "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" & Chr(34) & "/> " & Chr(13) & _
 "</RECORD> " & Chr(13) & _
 "<ROW> " & Chr(13) & _
  "<COLUMN SOURCE=" & Chr(34) & "1" & Chr(34) & " NAME=" & Chr(34) & "SPA" & Chr(34) & " xsi:type=" & Chr(34) & "SQLNVARCHAR" & Chr(34) & "/> " & Chr(13) & _
  "<COLUMN SOURCE=" & Chr(34) & "2" & Chr(34) & " NAME=" & Chr(34) & "VariantCode" & Chr(34) & " xsi:type=" & Chr(34) & "SQLNVARCHAR" & Chr(34) & "/> " & Chr(13) & _
  "<COLUMN SOURCE=" & Chr(34) & "3" & Chr(34) & " NAME=" & Chr(34) & "Rebate" & Chr(34) & " xsi:type=" & Chr(34) & "SQLNVARCHAR" & Chr(34) & "/> " & Chr(13) & _
 "</ROW> " & Chr(13) & _
"</BCPFORMAT> "

' Creates Variant XML File
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set a = fs.CreateTextFile(TempPath & "\VariantsFormat.xml", True)
a.WriteLine (XmlText)
a.Close
```

SQL:

```
CustVarParam as (SELECT  a.SPA+'-'+a.VariantCode as CustVar, cast(a.Rebate as Decimal(10,2)) as RebateValue   FROM    OPENROWSET(BULK 'U:\temp\Variants.csv', FORMATFILE= 'U:\temp\VariantsFormat.xml') AS a where a.SPA <> 'SPA') 

Select XXX
From XX
Where variant_detail.vad_variant_code In  ((Select CustVarParam.CustVar from CustVarParam))))
```