# Trouble with text of very long Teradata query

Tags: excel, vba, teradata, excel-2007

I am using the following function to perform a Teradata query from EXCEL 2007:

```
    Function Get_Query_Results(Rng As Range, Location As String, var As String, UID As String, PWD As String) As Long
    On Error GoTo TroubleWithTeradata
        Rng.Select
        With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:="ODBC;DSN=Server12;UID=" & UID & ";PWD=" & PWD & ";", Destination:=Rng).QueryTable
            .CommandText = var
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .BackgroundQuery = True
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .PreserveColumnInfo = True
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With
        Get_Query_Results = LastInCol(Columns(Location)) - 1
        Exit Function
    TroubleWithTeradata:
        Get_Query_Results = -1
    End Function
```

This query puts its results in a region whose "North West" corner is some cell specified by *Rng*, and determines how many records were returned by getting the row number of the last record in column number *Location*, which is what the function *LastInCol* (not listed here) returns. If the query doesn't fail but returns no records (i.e., only a header row), the number of records returned is 0. If the function does indeed fail, the number of records returned is -1.

The text of the Teradata query itself is contained in string *var*. And herein lies the problem. I have been using this function successfully for years. But  now I need to build a new query that makes the variable *var* exceed the EXCEL VBA limit of 32767 characters.

I really am not sure what limits are being exceeded here. Certainly that of the length of the variable *var*, but there's also what the QueryTable parameter *.CommandText* can contain.

How can I get around these limits?

Comment: Where/how are you getting `var`?  There's no VBA (string) limit of 32k characters, but there is I think a limit to the number of characters you can place in a cell.

Comment: I build it elsewhere and pass it to the function as argument.

Comment: Previously: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49254681/is-there-a-workaround-for-the-maximum-length-of-an-odbcconnection-commandtext-st  or  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26360651/odbc-connection-command-text

Comment: You are right.  I just verified that the size of the variable var is not being exceed.  Its current length is 43432.  That strongly indicates that .CommandText has a limit that is being exceeded.

Comment: Yes - seems like its ~32k

Comment: Jeez...  I did search for this and somehow didn't find it.  Thanks for the links to similar questions.  I'll study them.